accumulation point of spectrum of one-dimensional Schrödinger operator
Consider a one-dimensional Schrödinger operator $H=-\partial_x^2+V(x)$, with $V(x)$ a smooth function. If $\lambda$ is an accumulation point of the point spectrum of $H$, I would like to show that $\lambda$ is actually the supremum of the spectrum. Is this result true, and if so is there a simple proof thereof?
